# Passing JSON from js to flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I'm new to this. So I'm tring to pass json array from js to flask with this:

```
ElemButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      $.getJSON("/history/save", { wordlist: JSON.stringify(Hist_data) })
    })
```

and then save it into a json file on the flask side with this:

```
@app.route("/history/save")
def save():

  wordlist = json.loads(request.args.get('wordlist'))

  with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(wordlist, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

  return "saved"
```

Seems like it works just fine with small array, but when I'm tring to send larger one (2.8 MB) I keep getting this 2 error masseges. From Chrome's console:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at '`http://127.0.0.1:5000/history/save?wordlist=%5B%7B%22time%22%3A1628563166.134%2C%22open%22%3` . . .*

and at the end:

*. . .  00000%22%7D%5D' from origin '`http://127.0.0.1:5000`' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.*

Second error:

*Failed to load resource: `net::ERR_FAILED`*

Are there any restrictions on the size and if so what should I use to get this done?

I've tried both with key:
`$.getJSON("/history/save", { key: JSON.stringify(Hist_data) })`
and with wordlist:
`$.getJSON("/history/save", { wordlist: JSON.stringify(Hist_data) })`
Doesn't work either way. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Flask has a built in object called request. In request there is a multidict called args.

You can use request.args.get('key') to retrieve the value of a query string.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/example')
def example():
# here we want to get the value of the key (i.e. ?key=value)
value = request.args.get('key')`
```

Of course this requires a get request (if you use a post then use request.form). On the javascript side you can make a get request using pure javascript or jquery. I'm going to use jquery in my example.

```
$.get(
  url="example",
  data={key:value}, 
  success=function(data) {
    alert('page content: ' + data);
  }
);
```

This is how you pass data from the client into flask. The function portion of the jquery code is how you pass data from flask to jquery. Let's say for example you have a view called /example and from the jquery side you pass in a key value pair of "list_name":"example_name"

```
from flask import jsonify
def array(list):
string = ""
for x in list:
    string+= x
return string

@app.route("/example")
def example():
list_name = request.args.get("list_name")
list = get_list(list_name) #I don't know where you're getting your data from, humor me.
array(list)
return jsonify("list"=list)
```

success function in jquery you'd say

```
   success=function(data) {
   parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)
   alert('page content: ' + parsed_data);
}
```

Comment: Is that different from what I'm doing?